# Nginx failed to build on a Ubuntu Droplet (Digital Ocean / Laradock)

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, nginx, devops, laradock

I'm trying to upload a laradock environment on an Ubuntu droplet in DigitalOcean, however, it returns me a failure while starting nginx.

adduser: group 'www-data' in use
ERROR: Service 'nginx' failed to build: The command '/ bin / sh -c apk update && apk upgrade && apk add --no-cache openssl && apk add --no-cache bash && adduser -D -H -u 1000 -s / bin / bash www-data 'returned a non-zero code: 1

See the image below:

[image]

What can I do to resolve this problem?

I reinstalled version 19 of Ubuntu and did not succeed either.
On my Mac OS X it starts normally.
I also tried reinstalling the containers without the cache and it also did not work.

Comment: At the moment [the issue is open on laradock github](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/2166) and I hope it's being solved. As a temporary solution try to replace nginx by **caddy** service, it may help you.

Comment: Looks like the issue is resolved, [link](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/2160)